# Taking Photos Simply android example

Tags: android

I am try take a photo and save in Android. I have read this tutorial [take photo simple android training](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

In the tutorial i see that we get Uri by

> FileProvider.getUriForFile()

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.example.android.fileprovider",photoFile);
```

but when i click button download example and download demo from there, the code in this example create Uri by

> Uri.fromFile()

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
```

I have seen that compileSdkVersion of example is 25 but my project use

> compileSdkVersion 26

so if i use  Uri.fromFile() my project get error (no error if we change compileSdkVersion of my project 26 to 25, but i think i should not do that)

So my question is How we can Take Photo with FileProvider and compileSdkVersion >= 26.

Comment: Maybe you need `grantUriPermission` for that.

Answer (score 2):

A great way of taking and storing pictures in android is to use the EasyImage library. EasyImage allows you to easily capture images from the gallery, camera or documents without creating lots of boilerplate.

Have a look at the [EasyImage](https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage) android link.

Basic usage is as follows, for advance usage please refer the link above.

To directly open the camera:

```
EasyImage.openCamera(Fragment fragment, int type);
```

In your *onActivityResult()* you can again use EasyImage and use it's *handleActivityResult()* method to override it's two methods *onImagePickerError()* and *onImagesPicked()* to do the relevant work.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example take photo with Content provider and compileSdkVersion 26. I put my code here for anyone need

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {

            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    "com.funny.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            Log.d("=DEBUG=",photoURI.toString());
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            NewNoteActivity.this.grantUriPermission("com.example.funny.stickynote",photoURI, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            NewNoteActivity.this.grantUriPermission("com.example.funny.stickynote",photoURI, FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            takePictureIntent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            takePictureIntent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            //takePictureIntent.setData(photoURI);
            NewNoteActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_OK, takePictureIntent);
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            //if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //}

        }
    }
}
```

When receive the result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(moreOptionDialog.isShowing()==true)
    {
        moreOptionDialog.dismiss();
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_note_size),
                (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_note_size)
        );

        lp.setMargins(
                (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_note_margin),
                (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_note_margin),
                (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_note_margin),
                (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_note_margin)
        );

        // Do other work with full size photo saved in mLocationForPhotos
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        //imageView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(NewNoteActivity.this, R.color.blue));
        imageView.setLayoutParams(
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(lp)
        );
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);


        imageListAreaLinearLayout.addView(imageView, lp);
    }
}
```

in the manifest.xml

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.funny.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

file_paths

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="pic" path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```